# HTML replaceWith function with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to execute this code in javascript:

```
 $('#content').replaceWith("<div>" + <?php echo $tableau_Text?> + "</div>");
```

But is not working for me. It shows nothing to me. When I change the `PHP code` for something static like:

```
 $('#content').replaceWith("<div>Hello World</div>");
```

it works perfectly with that.

My html #content definition is:--

```
<div id="content">
    <?php echo $show_menu;?>
</div>
```

Any idea? Thank you very much!

UPDATE:

The var `$tableau_text` looks like this:

```
$tableau_Text = "<ul class='object_list' id='object_list' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-theme='c'>$TableauText</ul>";
```

Where `$TableauText` are the list items in the same format.

```
$TableauText = <li class='menuA' id='menuA' data-role='list-divider' data-icon='false'>River Flow</li>
<li class='menuB' id='menuB' data-icon='arrow-r'><a href='#' target='foo'>Rossiniere</a></li>
<li class='menuB' id='menuB' data-icon='arrow-r'><a href='#' target='foo'>Montsalvens</a></li>
<li class='menuA' id='menuA' data-role='list-divider' data-icon='false'>Lake Level</li>
<li class='menuB' id='menuB' data-icon='arrow-r'><a href='#' target='foo'>Rossiniere</a></li>
<li class='menuB' id='menuB' data-icon='arrow-r'><a href='#' target='foo'>Montsalvens</a></li>
<li class='menuB' id='menuB' data-icon='arrow-r'><a href='#' target='foo'>Lessoc</a></li>
<li class='menuB' id='menuB' data-icon='arrow-r'><a href='#' target='foo'>Rossens</a></li>
<li class='menuB' id='menuB' data-icon='arrow-r'><a href='#' target='foo'>Maigrauge</a></li>
<li class='menuB' id='menuB' data-icon='arrow-r'><a href='#' target='foo'>Schiffenen</a></li>
<li class='menuB' id='menuB' data-icon='arrow-r'><a href='#' target='foo'>Maigrauge</a></li>
```

Solution: I had several list elements with the same id which I didn't realized after I paste it here and that was making my code crazy...

Comment: This heavily depens on how `$tableau_Text` looks like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#content').replaceWith("<div>" + <?php echo json_encode($tableau_Text); ?> + "</div>");
```

Given:

```
$TableauText = 'hello world ""';

$tableau_Text = "
        <ul class='object_list' id='object_list' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-theme='c'>
        $TableauText
        </ul>";
```

The browser will see:

```
$('#content').replaceWith("<div>" + "\n        <ul class='object_list' id='object_list' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-theme='c'>\n        hello world \"\"\n        <\/ul>" + "</div>")​
```

Which [renders](http://jsfiddle.net/DQqMN/1/) as

```
hello world ""
```

Comment: @Lucia: Imagine this problem as a set of layers. Every layer treats it's unterlying layer as simple string and does not care about syntax. So your top layer is PHP, then JavaScript and finally HTML. In every layer you have to pay attention to quote/escape the results correctly to generate valid code/markup in the underlying layer. So in your case you don't need to concatenate the PHP output `<?php echo $tableau_Text?>` with the static JavaScript strings `"<div>"`.

Comment: Sorry guys, all my previous stuff was based on the variable called `_text`. I didn't think someone would store html in a variable called text.

Comment: Is not working!It looks like it doesn't compile, because everything stops working! Any other suggest`?

Comment: @Lucia what is the error message you see? Is your php version >= 5.2 ?

Comment: With your last update I get no error! It just don't show all the info, but I suppose its some problem with the json_encode and the format of html!!Thank you very much!

Comment: @Lucia there is probably problem with html. What is `$TableauText`?

Comment: I get everydata but I loose the format. I think there is no problem with $tableau_text because when I set as default content instead of replace it works perfectly, it's just the way I use it with replaceWith()

Comment: @Lucia If you lose the format, then you probably have invalid html and the browser doesn't use the html.  You should edit your html into the question. What is `$TableauText`?

Comment: @Lucia you have elements with same `id`. Every ID must be unique. Here's what I get with your html: http://jsfiddle.net/DQqMN/2/

Comment: Me too, and it should look like the image I will update in 30 secs!!

Comment: I updated the libraries in the jsfiddle and I get the right output but not in my browser!

Comment: @Lucia your problem is now with CSS, not php javascript or html anymore. You should add the css file to your page or something. But your original problem is solved and in SO we don't like extended discussion. You should accept best answer and make another question about CSS.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I really appreciate your time!! xD

Comment: My real problem was the thing with the ID's! It was not working properly because I didn't realized I had several with the same!

Answer (score 3):

Don't treat php code as variable

Try this

```
$('#content').replaceWith("<div><?php echo $tableau_Text?></div>");
```

Comment: @Esailija where i can't see any newlines in the question

Comment: Since comments are not multi-line I cannot show it in a comment :-). But every `li` element is separated by a newline in the OP for example.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your `<?php echo $tableau_Text?>` outputs the relevant text surrounded in quotes, you'll end up with invalid string concatenation and therefore a JavaScript syntax error. However, since the PHP is executed before the JavaScript gets to the browser, you don't need to use string concatenation at all.

Comment: this would be his point  $('#content').replaceWith("<div><?php echo $tableau_Text?></div>");

Answer (score 1):

One counter question : 
is your code

```
$('#content').replaceWith("<div>" + <?php echo $tableau_Text?> + "</div>");
```

in .js file?

if so this want work. and you shoul do this before including js

```
var tableau_Text  = ' <?php echo $tableau_Text?>';
<script src = 'any_js.js'></script>
```

and in .js

```
$('#content').replaceWith("<div>" + tableau_Text + "</div>");
```

Comment: than I am going with Anthony Grist's answer. :)

Comment: try this  $('#content').replaceWith("<div><?php echo $tableau_Text?></div>");