# Load JQUery Mobile before php executes

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing a JQuery mobile web app and I am having some problems with the format after executing 
    $('#someId').replaceWith(php var);

The problem, I think, is that as this is executed before the JQuery Mobile libraries are loaded I get a crappy format when I replace.

Can anyone think on something that could help?

Thank you very much!

UPDATE:

I'm quite new to PHP. What I want to do is to have several variables with the div html code in a way that when I click any button I don't have to refresh the page, just to refresh the div. This data is comming from an external database, so I need to do it with php... any ideas??

Comment: i have seen your code before and you can't do that client-side before server-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply said, all your browser-code is build by a server-side script and is interpreted right after the server-side script has finished. To do what you want to do, you need to utilize some ajax-actions...

Answer (score 2):

You will never be able to load a client side library (jQuery mobile) before the server side code (PHP) has been executed. Give us some code on what you want to do and I am sure we can help you better.

Comment: The only way to do that is ajax. But I dont believe that this is what would help here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612543/html-replacewith-function-with-php This is what I want to do!! Thanks! xD